# How to change the default database for login in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permissions, sysdba

I was trying to change the default database for logins in the sql server instance to the database they are mapped to. Currently, the default database of all logins in master database.

```
Alter login login-name with default_database = --'NEED HELP HERE to put the logic'
```

Thanks

Comment: What if the login is mapped to (have a user in) more than one database?

Comment: @Tibor, That is a good point. Anyone of the databases should be fine. My requirement is logins shouldn't have a default database that is not mapped to them.

Comment: Is there a problem having it as master? (Just asking.) Since guest is enabled in master, then they everybody can access master. In the end, you could do something like use a cursor to loop the databases, and for each user that exists in the database change that user's login's default database. After going through each (relevant) database those logins left with master as default would be those who aren't users in any database (very likely your sysadmins and "orhpaned logins"). One question is whether this is a one-off or something you would rune regularly?...

Answer (score 0):

This query will help you to set any default database to all/specified login, it is mapped with.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
[Login] sysname,
DBName varchar(512)
)

insert into #temp
exec sp_msforeachdb 'USE ? select name [login],db_name() from sys.database_principals where type=''U'' and [name] not like ''##%'''
-- Here you can add "where [name]= ''Login_name'' " if you want to set default database for specific login
DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(1024)
DECLARE My_Cursor CURSOR FOR
    select 'ALTER LOGIN '+[Login]+' WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=['+DBName+']'
    from
    (
    select
            distinct row_number() over(partition by t.[Login] order by t.DBName) Id,[Login],t.DBName
    from    #temp t inner join syslogins s on t.[Login]=s.[name]
    ) a

where Id=1

OPEN My_Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM My_Cursor INTO @QUERY
WHILE @@fetch_status=0
    BEGIN
    EXEC (@QUERY);
    FETCH NEXT FROM My_Cursor INTO @QUERY
    END
CLOSE My_Cursor
DEALLOCATE My_Cursor
```

Comment: thank you very much. Is it possible to get the same result without creating a temp table? My requirement is with out creating anything.

Comment: We can also do it using table variable. In both cases we'll have to store data in temporary object. because sys.database_principals holds login information at DB level and to check what are the databases mapped with a login, we'll have to pull records from each databases. And apply logic on that.